# Pure-ftpd-mysql dpkg problem

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I have problem with pure-ftpd-mysql. When i try remove pure-ftpd-mysql all time i have same issue:

```
root@vps438255:/var/lib/dpkg/info# apt-get remove --purge pure-ftpd-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  pure-ftpd-mysql*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 559 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 112166 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing pure-ftpd-mysql (1.0.43-3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/pure-ftpd-mysql.prerm: 18: /var/lib/dpkg/info/pure-ftpd-mysql.prerm: update-inetd: not found
dpkg: error processing package pure-ftpd-mysql (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/pure-ftpd-mysql.postinst: 34: /var/lib/dpkg/info/pure-ftpd-mysql.postinst: update-inetd: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pure-ftpd-mysql
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I try that comands to celar cache

```
apt-get clean

apt-get autoclean
```

But that still not working.

When i try put:

`apt-get update && upgrade` or `apt-get autoremove`

> root@vps438255:/var/lib/dpkg/info# apt-get autoremove
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    pure-ftpd-mysql : Depends: pure-ftpd-common (= 1.0.43-3) but it is not installed
>   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
>   You have new mail in /var/mail/root

I tried internet search something to solve my problem but nothing work.

Solved:
Just install `update-inetd` and run `apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: Is `update-inetd` (or `rlinetd`) installed? Looks like the prerm script is looking for it and failing because it is not installed.

Comment: I don't have that. What i should do?

Comment: Try installing `update-inetd`.

Comment: When i try install that from deb:https://pastebin.com/yitNDp88

Comment: And why from deb?

Comment: Deb becouse all time when i try from "apt-get install" i have error.Okay i solvd that :D i install that update-inetd and run apt --fix-broken install

Thats work :) thanks mate!

Answer (score 3):

The removal of `pure-ftpd-mysql` was failing because the pre-removal script tried to run `update-inetd`, which was not installed:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/pure-ftpd-mysql.prerm: 18: /var/lib/dpkg/info/pure-ftpd-mysql.prerm: update-inetd: not found
```

Installing `update-inetd` apparently solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Installing update-inetd {apt-get install -y update-inetd} solved my problem {Errors were encountered while processing: pure-ftpd-mysql E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)}.